# Prop and field?

Tags: c#, oop

[What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property-in-c)

I have read through this topic above but it is full of confusing answers with blah blah.

I want to know, in plain english, is this code below a field or property? . If it's a field, what is a property? If it's a property, what is a field?

```
class Door
{
     public int width { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: That’s a property. If it were `public int width;`, it would be a field.

Comment: Doesn't the comments in the accepted answer help you?

Comment: Have you looked at any resource other than SO?

Comment: getters and setters indicate a property.

Comment: @minitech post this as an answer, so I can pick you as chosen answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That's **a property.** It's the shorthand for creating a property with a getter, a setter, and a backing variable.

```
class Door
{
     public int width { get; set; }
}
```

The backing variable is anonymous, but basically the code that the compiler generates for that is the same as:

```
class Door {

  private int _width;

  public int width {
    get {
      return _width;
    }
    set {
      _width = value;
    }
  }

}
```

---

A **field** is just a public variable in a class or a struct, and would look like this:

```
class Door {

  public int width;

}
```

In this case the compiler doesn't create any code to handle the field, it's just a plain variable.

Comment: don't see much c# code with same-line curly brackets. I like it.

Comment: practical question: do you use public fields in real-world projects? Now I can see quite religious feelings around their prohibition.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov my teacher said fields are for kindergarten level. in real life you use only properties.

Comment: @ÖmerÖzkan: Yeah, I remember fields from kindergarten-level C#. Good old days. (Seriously, though — I use fields, and I hope this is real life.)

Comment: @minitech If you posted your first comment below my question as an answer, I Would pick you as best answer. Because it has been most helpful to me. Why dont you do it?

Comment: @ÖmerÖzkan: Your question is closed, so I can’t answer it. Besides, Guffa’s says the same thing now, at the bottom.

Comment: @minitech when I told you this, the question was open.

Comment: @ÖmerÖzkan: I don’t check for new comments continuously.

Comment: @minitech do you have problems regarding public fields with other team members? There is quite a lot of holy wars on the area, like: Properties doesn't "encapsulate" your implementation details, if your use auto-properties of generate properties based of fields.

Comment: @minitech It's sad because I liked your answer.

Comment: @ÖmerÖzkan: Do you dislike my answer for some reason? I noticed that you rather selected an answer that doesn't actually answer any of the questions...

Comment: @Guffa yes, because you rejected my small edit to make it bold on your answer.

Comment: @ÖmerÖzkan: I haven't rejected any edit. So you revenge-accepted the other answer because you thought that I rejected the edit?

Comment: @ÖmerÖzkan: So how do you feel now, that you know that I didn't reject any edit? Do you still want to keep the answer that doesn't answer your question, and doesn't say a single word about what you thought was so important?

Comment: @Guffa I made the edit again. If you accept it, I will select you as chosen answer :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a property is just a syntax for defining getters and setters for a field.

```
class Door
{
     public int width { get; set; }
}
```

is similar to

```
class Door
{
    private int width;

    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    public void setWidth(int i)
    {
        width = i;
    }
}
```